# OQPSK and MSK receiver sensitivity comparison

Tags: digital-communications, demodulation, communication-standard, gmsk, oqpsk

Which wireless receiver has the better sensitivity for the same everything except the change in the Base-band de-modulation, one base-band demodulator for OQPSK and other base-band demodulator for MSK, which one gives better sensitivity ?

Comment: that's undefined. You need to tell us what *kind* of demodulator you have; OQPSK and MSK are just two classes of modulation schemes (which overlap, too). There's different demodulators that you could have. And then you need to define what *kind* of noise you have.

Comment: @MarcusMüller All the system is exactly the same,  IF part of digital demodulator is the same too which is the complex filter + digital mixer, and the only difference is in the baseband demodulator, so conceptually which scheme of them could get better sensitivity at the receiver input

Comment: again, saying "OQPSK" doesn't define the baseband demodulator. Neither does saying "MSK". A scheme doesn't have sensitivity per se. A demodulator, applied to a scheme under a noise model does.

Answer (score 1):

MSK is a band efficient modulation type with 1 bit/sec/Hz. On the other hand, OQPSK is of 2 bit/sec/Hz.  MSK is equivalent to BPSK as well as OQPSK is equivalent to QPSK in terms of bit error rate. Therefore, when an uncoded scenario is considered, MSK is of a 3 dB of coding gaing compared to QPSK. In addition, the constant envelope of MSK is a huge benefit for non-linear amplifiers, yet the throughput is decreased by half.